# Is it possible for a web server to obtain a TOR browsers real IP with only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, ip, tor

Is it possible for a web server to obtain a TOR browsers real IP using only Javascript on the client and server side scripting on the server (cgi/perl/python or whatever)?  If so can I see an example script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *only* JavaScript and a properly functioning modern browser that sends all traffic over TOR, no, a web server cannot get your private IP.  However, it's hard to configure TOR so that *all* traffic is going over it and it's not that hard to combine other tactics with JavaScript to reveal your public IP.

See, for example, [Panopticlick](http://panopticlick.eff.org/), which shows that your browser fingerprint is probably unique already without any hacking. So if anything (like Flash or a PDF reader or Java) sends traffic outside of Tor it can correlate your Tor address with your public IP address.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. The only possible think you can do client-side (JavaScript won't let you, by the way) is looking at the client's network card address but most likely it will be an internal address (like `192.168.1.10`). Not very useful.

Establishing a connection to a server is also useless, since if the browser is configured to use TOR, it will use TOR for this connection and you'll get a TOR ip again (just as your server sees it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly what was recently done by the NSA.  It was widely reported and the exploit was discussed at length.  In fact, the client MAC address was even reported back to the attacker.

This is why Javascript and indeed all scripting should always be disabled in the browser.